# Intellij Idea shows files from nested git repositories as "add new" even when the directories are ignored in .gitignore

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

I have a directory A with child directories B and C.

All 3 of them are separate git repositories.

In order to avoid confusion, I have added B/ and C/ to A/.gitignore

When i run `git status`  I can only see changes from directory A.

But, when I try to see the changes via Intellij Idea - it also shows all the files under directories B and C as "add new" files.

[image: printscreen of Intellij Idea]

How can I avoid it?

*git - 2.19.1.windows.1

Intellij Idea - 2021.1.2*

Comment: Are you saying the you have clone git repos inside a parent git repo?!

Comment: Not clones. Just separate repos for different products. The reasons for this strange structure are various and include legacy apps, technology gaps and people's laziness. But that's not the question that I have asked.

Comment: You can do "Group By repository" and more likely you will see these files listed in repositories B and C.
You can disable git integration for these repositories under Preferences | Version Control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I have found is:

Goto File > Settings > Version Control

The 3 repositories (A,B,C) are shown there.

Perform "Remove" on B and C.
[image: Remove the not required repositories]

Also, the answer of @Ruslan Kuleshov is a very good alternative

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking for exactly this: The layout and naming has been changed and you can find it here in 2022.1.3: 

Preferences > Version Control > Directory Mappings